# SQL Server 2008 create an SP use a value if one is passed otherwise use default value

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure which is being used by many pages in an existing application. I would like to call it from a new page and pass an extra value into it without causing issues with all the other pages that call it. Inside the stored procedure I would like it to detect if the extra parameter/value is there, if so use it otherwise ignore it and use a default value. I am unsure how to change the stored procedure.

Here is how its being called from the existing pages:

```
sql = "exec spInsertNewLic " & value1 & "," & value2
```

and here is how I would like the new page to call it with the extra value:

```
sql = "exec spInsertNewLic " & value1 & "," & value & ", " & value3
```

How should I change the stored procedure, something like?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spInsertNewLic
(
@value1 int,
@value2 int,
@value3 date
)
AS
set nocount on
declare @myNewVariable date
if @value3 = 'NULL' or @value3 = '' set @myNewVariable = getDate() else @myNewVariable =  @value3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your SP to this, you set default value for value3 to null and then you don't have to change any existing code

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spInsertNewLic
(
@value1 int,
@value2 int,
@value3 date = null
)
AS
set nocount on
declare @myNewVariable date
if ISNULL(@value3,'') = '' --changed code here, NULL represents nothing
   set @myNewVariable = getDate() 
else 
   set @myNewVariable =  @value3
```